# Вывод определенных данных из mysql на PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: нужно вывести данные в таблицу(на экран) после их записи в mysql. Можно ли это сделать внутри цикла for? Если да то как? 
В этом коде я создаю 2 массива, далее я вычисляю, если данного элемента нет в mysql, то я его добавляю.

Таблица будет состоять из 2 колонок, в первой будет день недели,во второй раскрывающийся список с параметром дня недели.

```
<?php
...
$massivName = array ('mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun',
                     'WorkBeginR','WorkBeginKR','WorkBeginDO','WorkBeginHO',
                     'WorkEndR','WorkEndKR','WorkEndDO','WorkEndHO','DinnerR',
                     'DinnerKR','DinnerHO','DinnerTimeR','DinnerTimeKR','DinnerTimeHO');
$massivArg = array ('r','r','r','ho','kr','do','v','9:00','9:00','9:00','9:00','16:00',
                    '15:00','13:00','14:00','13:00','12:00','12:30','45','30','20');
$lengmass = count($massivName);
for ($i=0; $i < $lengmass; $i++){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM setup2 WHERE info = '{$massivName[$i]}'";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
  if ( mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    $sql = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT setup2 (info, setup)
                              VALUES ('{$massivName[$i]}','{$massivArg[$i]}');");
  }
}
```

Comment: @NewPhpUser, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: необходимо реализовать вывод только добавленных записей? или всех записей в таблице?

Comment: вывод конкретных данных из всей таблицы,например с 1 по 7 id.
те которые добавились не нужно выводить.